# How to retrieve monthly ordered data in SQL server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(datetime, call_start_time,100) 
    + CONVERT(datetime, call_start_time,120) as YEAR,
  SUM(call_duration) AS Total_CDR
FROM temp_txn_rated_retailcdr 
GROUP BY 
  CONVERT(datetime, call_start_time, 100) 
    + CONVERT(datetime,call_start_time,120) 
ORDER BY year DESC
```

I want to order the result on a month basis..please help me out. When I am doing this now it gets ordered by on the basis of an alphabetic character.

Comment: Your two convert datetime are meaningless. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Isn't `call_start_time` already a datetime? If you want to extract year try using `year(call_start_time)` and `month(call_start_time)` for month. Group and order on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work for you.

```
Select Month + ' ' + YEAR as c_Year,Total_CDR
    from 
    (
    SELECT 
        MONTH(call_start_time) AS Month
        ,YEAR(call_start_time) as YEAR 
        ,SUM(call_duration) AS Total_CDR
    FROM temp_txn_rated_retailcdr 
    GROUP BY MONTH(call_start_time),YEAR(call_start_time) 
    ) tbl
    ORDER BY YEAR desc,Month DESC
```